# How to stop the mediaplayer playing from other methods

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using this setOnClickListener() inside an one of the method in my Android App.Here I have used A mediaPlayer, which is declared locally.
Like this I also have two more methods which all uses mediaplayer. Also I have declared a global Mediaplayer & used it in various places of my onCreate().

```
public void setOnClickListenerWithMedia(ImageView iv,final int drawable,final int sound) {
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stopAllSoundsAndClearMemory();
        switchCases();
        iv_gone();
        fullscreenImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fullscreenImage.setImageResource(drawable);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sound);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is if I click on any other method, I have to stop the MediaPlayer. For Globally declared MediaPlayer Object(mp.). I can directly use,

```
if(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying()){
  mp.stop();
}
```

and I can stop it. But **I also want to stop the sound from all the methods.** How is it possible?

P.S: -> If I use mp in all the methods , it is not playing the sound & saying to create static mediaPlayer.

Thank you.

Comment: What methods are you talking about? What are they supposed to do?

Comment: Plz see the edited code,I will create two more methods like this and use them somewhere in my code. If I call this method , sounds from other methods should be stopped. That's it.

Comment: In that case, you should just use a global MediaPlayer for everything.

Comment: Please see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423050/12272687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when you are creating new player assign it to Global `MediaPlayer` instance.

i.e

declare mediaPlayer like this

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

And then in your `onClick` or in other other methods use like this

And check whether `MediaPlayer` already exist or not

```
f(mp!=null&&mp.isPlaying()){
  mp.stop();
  mp.release();
}
mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sound);
mp.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

try to design your mediaplayer as a singleton mode, and then your mediaplayer will be created only one instance object through the whole app.