# How to stop MediaPlayer onPause() if i declare/start it inside the onButtonClick method?

Tags: android, onclick, media-player, android-mediaplayer, onpause

I am a noob programer and I encountered a problem, I have a        `mediaplayer.start()` inside an `onClick` method, if i call

```
mediaplayer.stop(); 
mediaplayer.reset();
mediaplayer.release();
```

it will crash and get the error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.stop()' on a null object reference ".

I tried [How to stop the mediaplayer playing from other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418589/how-to-stop-the-mediaplayer-playing-from-other-methods) but when I used it I've got a:

> "Unable to destroy activity {...Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException"

Any support is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the `MediaPlayer` is `null`:

```
if(mediaplayer != null) {
    mediaplayer.stop(); 
    mediaplayer.reset();
    mediaplayer.release();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the lines where you start the sound as well as the definition of the `mediaplayer` variable please? Just edit your question to include the code.

Comment: It worked in the end i just declared the mediaplayer global and public, ty !

Comment: I assumed that you already defined it public :D Anyway, nice to hear that it works now! :)