# Stop and Replay an audio file

Tags: android, audio

What i am trying to accomplish is I stopped the music, then when I press the play button again, the media player will play it. 
But the problem I facing now is after I pressed the stop button, I can't play the music again.
Here is my code:

```
Button play,pause,stop;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.audio_beginagain);

    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    final MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(Audio_BeginAgain.this, R.raw.beginagain);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.start();
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.pause();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.stop();
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: you need to initialize  MediaPlayer  again after stop button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly what Md Abdul Gafur said..

Each time you want re-play the `MediaPlayer` you must initialize it new with `create()`.

Look at this code:

```
public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.far);
                mp.start();
            }

        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.beet);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
    }
}
```

Code copied from: [Android MediaPlayer Stop and Play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266668/4933902)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a completion listener and then use `mediaPlayer.seekto(0)` and `start()`:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
}
```