# How can I stop the MediaPlayer when Home key is pressed?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
  MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.background);
  player.start();
```

The Code above is part of the current code.
When I press the home key, MediaPlayer does not stop playing.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (KeyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            System.exit(0);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}
```

I've implemented the code shown above, for when you press the Back key.
Do you think that the above code is correct? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you using the media player in activity? if yes you can stop it in the onPause() method

Comment: You call `player.stop()` - to stop the player - did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Just implement below methods for this,

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
      super.onStop();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

      if(player != null)
             player.stop();

 }
```

Comment: Make sure that you release the `MediaPlayer` resources that you created on destroying the activity, by calling `player.release()` and nullifying the `MediaPlayer` in `onDestroy()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this solution:

```
public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.far);
                mp.start();
            }

        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.beet);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
    }
}
```

For more information, please read this post: [Android MediaPlayer Stop and Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266502/android-mediaplayer-stop-and-play)

Answer (score 0):

If your media player is running on the activity you created, you can call `player.stop()` in `onStop()` method.

Edit:

- Your implementation is OK, but it only overrides the back key only. You have to override the home key also to stop the `player` on pressing the home key. (but, use `onStop()` instead as it calls when the user interface is hidden.)
- Do not use `System.exit()`, use `finish()` instead.
- If you using `finish()` method (which destroys the activity), make sure that you have released the `MediaPlayer` resources by calling `player.release()` and nullifying the player. (i.e. `player = null`)