# how to stop MediaPlayer correctly?

Tags: android-studio, media-player

I can stop the Audio but if I check my Android-Studio Debug windows, i see that the MediaPlayer works in Background !!!

I play the Sound like that :

```
try {
myMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
myMediaPlayer1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
myMediaPlayer1.setDataSource("http://myweb.com/audios/1.mp3");
myMediaPlayer1.prepare();
myMediaPlayer1.start();    
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
```

I stop the MediaPlayer via a click on a Button or OnDestry like that :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    myMediaPlayer1.stop();
}
```

I debug via USB Connection. After Stop the Sound I see the MediaPlay works in Background :
[image: Here is the Screenshot:]

Comment: Please see this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423050/12272687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release media player using `mediaPlayer.release()`. If `MediaPlayer` is not playing any song/audio you shouldn't stop `MediaPlayer`. See below code for more help.

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works :


               `myMediaPlayer1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer1) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
            }
        });`