# how to Stop the song when another song is play

Tags: android

I  am try to create a stream player  i am using this code to stop the song when another song will play but this code does not work . both songs play together i want to play one by one or if any other song will clicked the stop the previous song and play that song. Any one can help me.

```
 try {

                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource(upload.getUrl());
                if(player.isPlaying())
                {
                    player.stop();
                }
               else {

                   player.prepare();
                   player.start();
               }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266502/android-mediaplayer-stop-and-play

Answer (score 0):

You have to release your `mediaplayer` to stop

```
player.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
try {

            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setDataSource(upload.getUrl());
            if(player.isPlaying())
            {
                player.stop();
                player.release();//change here
            }
           else {

               player.prepare();
               player.start();
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```