# How to properly adjust the sound when pressing the button in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a game where you have to memorize the sequence of clicks on 4 buttons. If i press the buttons several times, the sound of pressing disappears.

I tried to adjust the sound when clicking on them, click sound takes 1 second. Tell me where I made a mistake and how to do it right.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mainView: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var sound: MediaPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainView = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mainView.root)

        mainView.apply {

            blueButton.setOnClickListener {
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.blue_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            redButton.setOnClickListener {
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.red_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            greenButton.setOnClickListener {
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.green_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            yellowButton.setOnClickListener {
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.yellow_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

        }
    }

    private fun play(buttonSound: MediaPlayer) {
        buttonSound.start()
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `constantly press`? You press the button once and leave your finger on the button for more than 0.5 seconds (=`LongClick`), or you press and release the button several times in succession? How many seconds takes `R.raw.blue_bt_tap_sound`? `If you constantly press the keys, the sound of pressing disappears over time.`: Is that a feature in your app or the problem?

Comment: @cloverleaf, several times* After about 30 clicks the sound stops playing. At the same time, it does not matter whether i pressed different buttons or only one. Sound takes 1.1 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add method `stop()`:

```
private fun stop() {
    sound?.stop()
    sound?.release()
    sound = null
}
```

Then stop the player if it's not null before creating a new one:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainView = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(mainView.root)

        mainView.apply {

            blueButton.setOnClickListener {
                stop()
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.blue_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            redButton.setOnClickListener {
                stop()
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.red_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            greenButton.setOnClickListener {
                stop()
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.green_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

            yellowButton.setOnClickListener {
                stop()
                sound = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.yellow_bt_tap_sound)
                play(sound)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop and release the `MediaPlayer`, before you play another sound. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75423050/22820043) for the required commands in Kotlin, but read first **all other** answers there. They are written in Java, but you should still understand them.